# How to separate multiple text values with comma flutter using rest api

Tags: flutter

```
child: Text(
// addres["address_1"],
   addres["firstname"] + addres["lastname"] + addres["address_1"] + addres["city"] + addres["country"],
   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
   maxLines: 3,
   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
),
```

I would like to separate the addres values with comma. I am getting these values from rest api.

Comment: Do you want to print only these fields of 'addres' or you want to print all the fields of 'addres'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood correctly, this is what u want:

`"${addres["firstname"]}, ${addres["lastname"]}, ${addres["address_1"]}, ${addres["city"]}, ${addres["country"]}"`

Answer (score 1):

```
"${addres["firstname"]},${addres["lastname"]},${addres["address_1"]},${addres["city"]},${addres["country"]}"
```